# Express and the Node.js module i18n and the now lack of helpers

Tags: node.js, internationalization, express

From the README at https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node they show how to set it up with express templates but it uses helpers:

```
// register helpers for use in templates
app.helpers({
  __i: i18n.__,
  __n: i18n.__n
});
```

Well in Express 3.0 there are no helpers so how do I register the i18n module with the templates?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

helpers are now renamed to locals:

```
app.locals({
  __i: i18n.__,
  __n: i18n.__n
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct and could be marked so. even if my response was deleted by @BoltClock i want to mention that switching to http://i18next.com/node might be a good option - this might help others to find a good and uptodate solution to do i18n in node.js